# Angular Localstorage not working after ng build

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

In my angular 8 app I have used localStorage in the following way.

**To set item**

```
localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
```

**To get item**

```
var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
```

The app is working fine in development, but when I run ng build and run the app from dist directory it is not working. variables are undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Stop using var.

Comment: Look into this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

Comment: I have the same error, but only when deployed to my S3